# Android Download App from Google Play programmatically?

Tags: android

I am creating an Android app which depends on some other android apps. So if these dependent apps are not already there on the users mobile, I would like to download them programmatically from play store. But during this process I don’t want the control to go to the Play store app (i.e. no Play store app activity should be visible).Is it possible to use some Api or functionality to do that? I found two link but I think that  [link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/market-enabler/downloads). But I think such solution don't work no more.

Comment: installing an app requires the user to actually want to download the app. Usually that is done through the market, but you can also install the application from elsewhere, provided that you have the apk, and that the user allows external applications installation

Comment: It is not the problem of installing from apk or play store. I would like to install some application from a master (tablet or computer) in many tablets without launching any Activity related to playstore in  tablet.

Comment: my point is that if you have the apk, you can minimize the interaction by not actually going to the play store, but only going through the packagemanager, only prompting for the installation of the app.